# Login/Registration through Database in CQ5 or AEM

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to create Login/Registration/Forgot Password from Database itself in CQ5/AEM.

1. Login Page
2. Registration
3. User Activation
4. Approval Process
5. Landing Page after Login- How to configure on Dispatcher
6. Forgot Password.
   7.It should work as User management in CQ5/AEM

I know its a big requirement but if someonr can give me idea to implement it would be big help for me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ideal would be start with some logic to implement this functionality. If AEM is new for you then go through training manual.

Comment: Thanks Vivek for reply. i can implement custom logic to validate username and password, but how to maintain session through out the how it would be in dispatcher. thanks in advance if you can help on this.

Comment: you might have to deal with UserManager Apis in AEM. And validation is upto you how you perform that. To make it work on dispatcher your sign-in component should be non-cacheable. Use SDI for this.

Comment: I am confused here. Do you mean by through Database? do you want to store the user credentials in an external database?

Comment: yes, you get it. it already been stored